# Realtime Database + Authentication

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-auth

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para poder registrar usuarios y almacenarlos en realtime database, pero me encuentro que el primer usuario se registra y se guarda en database y el siguiente se registra borra el anterior y se guarda. También me pasa lo mismo con otra activity que es para añadir productos a la base de datos, pero borra directamente tanto el producto como el usuario.

```
    private void registrarUsuario(){

        final String email = TextMail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password  = TextPass.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Falta un email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Falta la contraseña",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        progressDialog.setMessage("Realizando registro...");
        progressDialog.show();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Se ha registrado el usuario con el email: "+ TextMail.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Map<String, Object> mapa = new HashMap<>();
                    mapa.put("email", email );
                    mapa.put("pass", password);
                    mDatabase.setValue(mapa);

                    String id = (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                   mDatabase.child("Usuario").child(id).setValue(mapa).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task1) {
                            if (task1.isSuccessful()){
                                Intent intencion = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intencion);
                                finish();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"No se han podido crear los datos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"No se pudo registrar el usuario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ojala pudieras agregar una imagen de la estructura de tu base de datos

pero creo que deberías quitar ese campo usuario.

```
mDatabase.child(id).setValue(mapa).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    ///^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task1) {
                        if (task1.isSuccessful()){
                            Intent intencion = new Intent(getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intencion);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"No se han podido crear los datos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

ya que así se crearía directamente desde el nodo que da FirebaseAuth.

como dije, ojalá se pudiera observar tu estructura en RealTimeDatabase, y si si tienes todas las dependencias conectadas correctamente.

Saludos, si no es así, disculpa!